# Extract part of a string from one column, paste into a new column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

Disclaimer: Totally inexperience with R so please bear with me!...

Context: I have a series of .csv files in a directory. These files contain 7 columns and approx 100 rows. I've compiled some scripts that will read in all of the files, loop over each one adding some new columns based on different factors (e.g. if a specific column makes reference to a "box set" then it creates a new column called "box_set" with "yes" or "no" for each row), and write out over the original files. The only thing that I can't quite figure out (and yes, I've Googled high and low) is how to split one of the columns into two, based on a particular string. The string always begins with ": Series" but can end with different numbers or ranges of numbers. E.g. "Poldark: Series 4", "The Musketeers: Series 1-3".

I want to be able to split that column (currently named Programme_Title) into two columns (one called Programme_Title and one called Series_Details). Programme_Title would just contain everything before the ":" whilst Series_Details would contain everything from the "S" onwards.

To further complicate matters, the Programme_Title column contains a number of different strings, not all of which follow the examples above. Some don't contain ": Series", some will include the ":" but will not be followed by "Series".

Because I'm terrible at explaining these things, here's a sample of what it currently looks like:

```
Programme_Title               
Hidden
Train Surfing Wars: A Matter of Life and Death
Bollywood: The World's Biggest Film Industry
Cuckoo: Series 4
Mark Gatiss on John Minton: The Lost Man of British Art
Love and Drugs on the Street
Asian Provocateur: Series 1-2
Poldark: Series 4
The Musketeers: Series 1-3
War and Peace
```

And here's what I want it to look like:

```
Programme_Title                                          Series_Details
Hidden
Train Surfing Wars: A Matter of Life and Death
Bollywood: The World's Biggest Film Industry
Cuckoo                                                   Series 4
Mark Gatiss on John Minton: The Lost Man of British Art
Love and Drugs on the Street
Asian Provocateur                                        Series 1-2
Poldark                                                  Series 4
The Musketeers                                           Series 1-3
War and Peace
```

As I said, I'm a total R novice so imagine that you're speaking to a 5 yr old. If you need more info to be able to answer this then please let me know.

Here's the code that I'm using to do everything else (I'm sure it's a bit messy but I cobbled it together from different sources, and it works!)

```
### Read in files ###
filenames = dir(pattern="*.csv")

### Loop through all files, add various columns, then save ###

for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
tmp <- read.csv(filenames[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
### Add date part of filename to column labelled "date" ###
tmp$date <- str_sub(filenames[i], start = 13L, end = -5L)
### Create new column labelled "Series" ###
tmp$Series <- ifelse(grepl(": Series", tmp$Programme_Title), "yes", "no")
### Create "rank" for Programme_Category ###
tmp$rank <- sequence(rle(as.character(tmp$Programme_Category))$lengths)
### Create new column called "row" to assign numerical label to each group ###
DT = data.table(tmp)
tmp <- DT[, row := .GRP, by=.(Programme_Category)][]
### Identify box sets and create new column with "yes" / "no" ###
tmp$Box_Set <- ifelse(grepl("Box Set", tmp$Programme_Synopsis), "yes", "no")
### Remove the data.table which we no longer need ###
rm (DT)
### Write out the new file###
write.csv(tmp, filenames[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to give us some data to work with, could you send us the output of `dput(head(tmp))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your exact data structure, but I created some example for you that should work:

```
library(tidyr)
movieName <- c("This is a test", "This is another test: Series 1-5", "This is yet another test")
df <- data.frame(movieName)
df
                         movieName
1                   This is a test
2 This is another test: Series 1-5
3         This is yet another test
df <- df %>% separate(movieName, c("Title", "Series"), sep= ": Series")

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$Series[row] <- ifelse(is.na(df$Series[row]), "", paste("Series", df$Series[row], sep = ""))
}
df
                     Title     Series
1           This is a test           
2     This is another test Series 1-5
3 This is yet another test
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to capture all the examples you might encounter, but you can easily add things to capture variants not covered in the examples I provided.

Edit: I added a test case that did not include : or series. It will just produce a NA for the Series Details.

```
## load library: main ones using are stringr, dplyr, tidry, and tibble from the tidyverse, but I would recommend just installing the tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

## example of your data, hard to know all the unique types of data, but this will get you in the right direction
data <- tibble(title = c("X:Series 1-6",
                         "Y: Series 1-2",
                         "Z : Series 1-10",
                         "The Z and Z: 1-3",
                         "XX Series 1-3",
                         "AA AA"))

## Example of the data we want to format, see the different cases covered
print(data)

  title           
  <chr>           
1 X:Series 1-6    
2 Y: Series 1-2   
3 Z : Series 1-10 
4 The Z and Z: 1-3
5 XX Series 1-3
6 AA AA   

## These %>% are called pipes, and used to feed data through a pipeline, very handy and useful.
data_formatted <- data %>%

  ## Need to fix cases where you have Series but no : or vice versa, this keep everything the same.
  ## Sounds like you will always have either :, series, or :Series If this is different you can easily
  ## change/update this to capture other cases
  mutate(title = case_when(
    str_detect(title,'Series') & !(str_detect(title,':')) ~ str_replace(title,'Series',':Series'),
    !(str_detect(title,'Series')) & (str_detect(title,':')) ~ str_replace(title,':',':Series'),
    TRUE ~ title)) %>% 

  ## first separate the columns based on :
  separate(col = title,into = c("Programme_Title","Series_Details"), sep  = ':') %>% 

  ##This just removes all white space at the ends to clean it up
  mutate(Programme_Title = str_trim(Programme_Title),
         Series_Details = str_trim(Series_Details))

## Output of the data to see how it was formatted
print(data_formatted)

  Programme_Title Series_Details
  <chr>           <chr>         
1 X               Series 1-6    
2 Y               Series 1-2    
3 Z               Series 1-10   
4 The Z and Z     Series 1-3    
5 XX              Series 1-3
6 AA AA           NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up trying the first response (above) which worked for me. But thanks again :)